# Delete docker specific images

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

I need some kind of Docker behaviour. Imagine docker image name is `imagename` and image also have tag(1, 2, 3 ...). Now I want to delete all images with the name `imagename` and with the tag that isn't `x`. For example if I have images:

```
imagename:1
imagename:2
imagename:3
imagename:4
imagename:5
imagename:6
```

with 1, 2, 3 ...6 tags, and I want to have only one Image with name `imagename` and tag 6, what command should I run?

Comment: What have you already tried?  Is there a specific tool set you're thinking of (the Python Docker API; `grep` and `xargs`; ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the `docker` command alone. I would use a small shell loop. For example remove every `python` image which is **not** tagged `3.6`:

```
docker images | awk -v img='python' -v tag='3.6' '$1==img && $2!=tag{print $3}' \
  | while read -r id ; do docker rmi "${id}" ; done
```

Comment: what is $2 and $3? I know they are passed as arguments when running the bash script, but what do they mean? $2 might be tag but what about $3?

Comment: Those variables aren't bash variables, they are `awk` variables. Their refer to the columns in the input of `awk` (which is the output of `docker images`)

Comment: somehow it deletes all images with name python

Comment: turns out some of them have same IDs

Comment: (1) It won't delete python:3.6 images. (2) If they have the same id, then you tagged the same image with different names